# Print command-line only on error in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile to compile a C-project and I want to improve it.

I would like to hide the commands used by the makefile unless there is an error.

Here is my rule

```
#==================================
# Text formatting for better output
OK  = "$@ \033[32;1m\xE2\x9C\x94\033[0m"

%.o: %.c
    @$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ && echo -e $(OK)
```

I have the errors and warnings from gcc in my terminal and make stops on errors as I wanted, however I would like to display the command that was executed by gcc which caused the error. Is it possible to use make to do this?

Comment: ITYM "text formatting for _worse_ output" for anybody whose stdout isn't connected to a terminal like yours...

Comment: You might be able to adapt the `cronic` program to print the executed command as well as the error output.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `echo -e` (or any option to `echo`, or any special characters passed to `echo`) in a portable makefile because it's inherently non-portable.  You can use `printf` instead.

There is nothing built-in to `make` that will do it for you.  But you can use a function to do it yourself, something like:

```
RUN = @$1 && printf '$(OK)' || { echo '$1'; false; }

%.o: %.c
        @$(call RUN,$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@)
```

However note that things are more complicated if you want to support command lines containing commas.

Also note that here the command will be printed AFTER the errors.  There's nothing you can do about that since you won't know whether the command failed until after you run it, except to redirect the output to a temporary file and only print it after the command fails.  But note that this loses all terminal formatting (colors etc.) that may be in the output.

My recommendation to all this is just "don't do it".  Instead of this, have a simple way to turn off the hiding of command lines.  If you want to see the commands, re-run your `make` with that setting so you can see the recipes.

Comment: I posted a link to my blog explaining how to implement "a simple way to turn off the hiding of command line", but some bot or editor for StackOverflow deleted it.  So, you'll just have to go look for it yourself if you want to know how to do it.